# comparing data with last 5 versions of feed data in C* using datastax,hadoop,hive

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive

I have a lot of data saved into Cassandra on a daily basis and I want to compare one datapoint with last 5 versions of data for different regions.

Lets say there is a price datapoint of a product and there are 2000 products  in a context/region(say US). I want to show a heat map dash board showing when the price change happened for different regions.

[image]

I am new to hadoop, hive and pig. Which path would help me achieve my goal and some details appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How often do you need the heatmap updated, and how frequently do the new versions of the price come in?

Comment: As soon as the data is in C*, heat map update would be ideal but anything is fine for now. New versions of price come in at the max two -3 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use case for either traditional mapreduce or [spark](http://spark.apache.org).  You have relatively infrequent updates, so a batch job running over the data and updating a table that in turn provides the data for the heatmap seems like the right way to go.  Since the updates are infrequent, you probably don't need to worry about spark streaming- just a traditional batch job run a few times a day is fine.

Here's some info from datastax on reading from cassandra in a spark job: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSCcontext.html

For either spark or mapreduce, you are going to want to leverage the (spark or MR) framework's ability to partition the task- if you are manually connecting to cassandra and reading/writing the data like you would from a traditional RDBMS, you are probably doing something wrong.  If you write your job correctly, the framework will be responsible for spinning up multiple readers (one for each node that contains the source data that you are interested in), distributing the calculation tasks, and routing the results to the appropriate machine to store them.

Some more examples are here:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkIntro.html

and

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/byoh/byohIntro.html

Either way, MapReduce is probably a little simpler, and Spark is probably a little more future proof.

Comment: If I go the map reduce route like in this example below, should I write some java code to pull the records from the tables and compare the contexts for price changes and dump data to another table to serve the heat map? I am really starting so please give me more details. http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/solutions/about_hadoop

Comment: Cool, I just ran the word count example and it ran fine(did spawn multiple readers). I will go the Spark route then. Thank you so much for your help with this.I have to spend time learning Spark and it might take only a couple days.http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaTut.html